# SVN: merging a branch which has moved in the repository

Tags: svn, version-control, merge, tortoisesvn, branching-and-merging

So, we have a fairly complex repository layout, the results of the move operation performed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27844340/svn-switch-vs-relocate-in-a-multiple-project-repository-case):

```
svn.contoso.com/root_repository_path/
    |- project1
    |- project2
    |    |- subprojectA
    |    |- subprojectB
    |- project3
    |- project4
    |-   |- subprojectA
    |-   |- subprojectB
    |    |- project5 (the project I'm on)
```

Each of these folders has a full trunk/branches/tags structure under it, and project5 specifically has several branches, all of which date back *before* the fellow developer from the linked question reorganized the repository.  Now, I need to merge a branch (let's call it the shiny-feature branch) back into another, 'parent' branch; thing is, (Tortoise)SVN gets confused when I try to merge the full revision range for the shiny-feature branch into the parent branch, giving me an error of the form:

```
'/svn/root_repository_path/!svn/bc/5555/project5/branches/shiny-feature' path not found
```

where 5555 is the current revision the repository is at.  Trying to merge just the revision that moved the branch yields a no-op merge, while excluding the branch-moving revision yields the exact same error as above.

How am I supposed to get this branch merged back in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this error was actually due to TortoiseSVN pre-filling the old path to the branch:

```
$REPO_URL/project4/branches/shiny-feature
```

instead of the current path to the branch:

```
$REPO_URL/project4/project5/branches/shiny_feature
```

Fixing this enabled the merge to work without an issue.

Answer (score 0):

First, is that branch visible elsewhere in your tree? If I understand correctly, `project5` was moved from the root of the repository tree to under `project4` where did its branches go?

Subversion usually doesn't have too many issues with merging when a branch itself is merged because it can easily walk down the tree from the old location to the new location. If `project5 still has it branches under it, this should be fine:

```
$ svn co $RSVP_URL/project4/project5/trunk project5-trunk
$ cd project5-trunk
$ svn merge $RSVP_URL/project4/project5/branches/shiny-feature
```

If that branch is no longer visible in your most recent revision of the tree, you have to resurrect it via `svn cp`:

```
$ svn cp -r4321 $REPO_URL/project5/branches/shiny-feature@4321 \
    $REPO_URL/project4/branches/shiny-feature
```

The `@4321` is a *pin revision*. You're saying you're interested in how the revision looked in revision before the shiny-feature branch was deleted. The `-r4321` says the revision you're copying of that shiny-branch.

Comment: Project5 has an *entire* trunk/branches/tags structure under it -- so the entire structure was moved at once, including the shiny-feature branch and its parent branch.  So, the shiny-feature branch is *not* visible elsewhere in the tree.

Comment: @LThode Can't you merge `$REPO_URL/project4/project5/branches/shiny-feature` into `$REPO_URL/project4/project5/trunk`? Subversion should be able to trace all the changes to merge even before the project was moved.

Comment: That fails as well, with the exact same error message as before.

Comment: Does `$REPO_URL/project4/project5/branches/shiny-feature` exist in your current repository tree. What happens if you specify `svn ls $REPO_URL/project4/project5/branches/shiny-feature` from the command line?

Comment: Yes it does exist in my current repository tree -- I figured out what it was though and will post an answer of my own.

Comment: Are you attempting to _cherry pick_ some revisions that don't exist in the current tree? You may have to add the _pin_ revision to it (The `@rev` at the end of the URL).

Comment: No -- see my answer above.